# vetical line in matlab semilogy plot

Tags: matlab, graph, plot, matlab-figure

The code is

```
figure;
x = 0:.1:20;
semilogy(x,10.^x);
hold on;
line([10 10],[0 10^10]);
```

But the vertical line doesn't show up, any idea?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: `log(0) = -Inf` -> war!

Comment: A very neat way of putting it :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `0` in `line([10 10],[0 10^10])`. Use

```
line([10 10],[1 10^10]);
```

A `0` value in log scale is problematic, as it would be infinitely down on the `y` axis.

Comment: It's embarrassing. Thank you very much. It would take me hours to find out.